# Multiple Angular 2 Application on Node.js Project

Tags: node.js, angular, express

Have Node.js project with two Angular2 application, I want to combine all (`site`, `admin` and `server`) `node_modules` into one. and I need to control all app from root directory.

[image]
[image]

Please suggest the solution or suggest the standardized method to do this.

Answer (score 0):

With angular cli [multiple apps feature](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-multiple-apps) you definitely can combine your two angular apps, which is make sence. But  I definitely recommend to keep your `server` app separate.
Like have a folder `src` with two folders `client`(angular apps) and  `server` in it.